# How to read txt from Matlab from a specific word

Tags: matlab, readfile

I have to read this txt file:

```
#Acceleration force along the x y z axes (including gravity).
#timestamp(ns),x,y,z(m/s^2)
#Datetime: 05/07/2013 11:27:39
##########################################
#Activity: 12 - BSC - Back sitting chair - 10s
#Subject ID: 1
#First Name: sub1
#Last Name: sub1
#Age: 32
#Height(cm): 180
#Weight(kg): 85
#Gender: Male
##########################################


@DATA 
2318482693000, 0.89064306, -9.576807, -0.019153614 2318492108000, 0.91937345, -9.595961, -0.05746084 2318503365000,
    0.8714894, -9.595961, -0.05746084 2318512831000, 0.8523358, -9.643845, -0.038307227 2318523222000, 0.8714894, -9.634268, -0.05746084 2318533156000, 0.90979666, -9.634268, -0.019153614 2318553207000,
    0.9672575, -9.634268, -0.009576807 2318563306000, 0.93852705, -9.672575, -0.009576807 2318575332000, 0.9672575, -9.682152, -0.009576807 2318584933000, 0.9672575, -9.662998, -0.009576807 2318595971000, 0.9576807, -9.634268, 0.009576807
```

And I have to save numbers after the word "@DATA" in a vector.
I don't know how to read a txt file from a certain word (in this case @DATA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
fid = fopen('yourfile.extension');
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    disp(tline) %just for debugging purposes
    if strncmp("@DATA",tline,5)
      break
    end
end
while ~feof(fid)
%start reading your data with fscanf for example
end
```

And never forget your search engine is your friend...

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feof.html

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large, you could load it as a character array and use a regular expression to parse it. It may not be the best method if you want code that's efficient on memory and scales to any file size, but IMO it's very straightforward.

```
txt = fileread(file);
valList = regexp(txt, '@DATA\n([\d\n\, \.-]+)', 'tokens');
vals = strsplit(valList{1}{1}, ', ');
```

That's pretty quick-and-dirty, and the regular expression will change depending on how you decide to format the file, but that should get you in the right direction. If you format the file more nicely, you can probably use a prettier expression.